# If the "Sentinel" Program existed since 1973 why it was never mentioned in the original trilogy of X-Men?

Tags: x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-days-of-future-past, marvel

In X-Men DoFP we see that Trask Industries had developed a program to wipe out all mutants (the Sentinels). In the original timeline, though, where Mystique kills Trask and the American Government approves the "Sentinel" Program, why do we never get a single mention of it in X-Men 1, 2 or 3? Is it secret and it is uncovered only a few years after X3?

*Note:* This question is obviously different than [that one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/56921/what-timeline-is-the-post-credit-scene-at-the-end-of-the-wolverine-in?lq=1) where the person who posted it is trying to figure out in which timeline every single event of the entire X-Men film series is happening, while my question is trying to explain if the absence of a mention to the "Sentinel" Program in the original X-Men trilogy is either a continuity error or is it explained somehow.

Comment: @keen that dupe does not answer this question.

Comment: How on Earth is this a duplicate of that other question?

Comment: @evilsoup They both ask about the issue of there not being Sentinels all over the place during the original 3 *X-Men* films.

Comment: @Keen Are you kidding? How am I supposed to find out that a question with a title referring to a completely different movie that has nothing to do with the "Sentinel" Program, answers my question? Do I have to read every single X-Men related question in this forum, even if the title doesn't help me find any relevance to my issue, just to exclude any duplicate possibility?

Comment: @PiXel1225 Marking something as a duplicate isn't a punishment.  It is exactly what the text says, "This question already has an answer."

Comment: @PiXel1225: You don't "need to exclude duplicate possibility". That's why other people can close-as-duplicate!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They did. X3 Danger room simulation scene:
[image]

Comment: That's not necessarily a Sentinel, just a big robot(head) in a Danger Room simulation, it could be they just conjured up a similar looking opponent since it's never explicitly referred to as one.  Unless you've got a source (script, or "word of god" from one of the producers/director) to back that up.

Comment: @Monty129 x3 storyboard for expanded Sentinel Danger Room sequence. http://www.blastr.com/2013-3-4/x-men-3-storyboards-show-action-packed-sentinel-scene-we-never-got-see Then again, Wolverine told Colossus to throw him, but never called it a fast ball special, so it might not have been a fast ball special either right?

Comment: I did some digging and found out that the Sentinels (and the Danger Room) was set to appear in X2 but due to budget issues, they were left out. So, the Sentinels did existed in the original timeline but due to budget cutting *we* never got to see them.

Comment: @PiXel1225 but they actually included them in X3 (see screenshot), so the point is moot.